# If $A$ is a non-empty set and $2^A$ is the power set of $A$. Is $2^A \subseteq A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, intuition

I'm aware that if there exists an injective map  $f: A \to 2^A$ then for each element $a\in A$ $\exists$ $f(a)\subseteq A$.

But does this also mean $f(a)\subseteq 2^A$?

I ask this because when writing out a simple numerical example of such a set, say $A=\{{ 7,8\}}$ then $2^A=\{{\varnothing,\{{ 7\}},\{{ 8\}},\{{7,8\}}\}}$, however since each $f(a)$ is an element of $2^A$ then we must have $f(a)\subseteq 2^A$ since *any* set $X$ is always a subset of itself: $X\subseteq X$ right?

Thank you.

Best Regards.

Comment: Actually, for $A=\{{ 7,8\}}$ you have $2^A=\{{\varnothing,\{7\},\{8\},\{{7,8\}}\}}$, not $\{{\varnothing,7,8,\{{7,8\}}\}}$,,

Comment: @CiaPan You're right, thank you, changed it now

Comment: What is "$f(a)$ represents all the elements of $2^A$" supposed to **mean**, and why do you think it's true?

Comment: Is the question in the **title** of your post supposed to have something to do with the various questions in the body?

Comment: What is "$f(a)$ is **the elements** of $2^A$" supposed to mean? Don't you mean "$f(a)$ is **an element** of $2^A$"?

Comment: @Bof thanks, I just changed the wording slightly, I think it means that each $f(a)$ is an element of the set $2^A$ and yes the questions in the body and title are related to each other.

Comment: **Why** do you think "is $2^A\subseteq A$" (from the title) is related to the subsequent questions? Anyway, the answer to your **title** is "no"; $2^A$ is **never** a subset of $A$.

Comment: @Bof "Anyway, the answer to your title is "no"; 2A is never a subset of A", Great! Now can you please explain why?

Comment: The set $R=\{a\in A:a\notin a\}$ is an element of $2^A$ (since it's a subset of $A$), but it's not an element of $A.$

Comment: If you assume (as one often does) that a set can't be an element of itself, then it's even simpler: the set $A$ itself is an element of $2^A$ but is not an element of $A,$ so $2^A\not\subseteq A.$

Comment: $X\subseteq X$ is right, and from $X\subseteq X$ it follows that $2^A\subseteq2^A,$ and also that $f(a)\subseteq f(a)$ for each $a$ in $A$; but I don't see how it follows that $f(a)\subseteq2^A.$

Comment: @bof thanks you have answered the title question correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To a question in title**

No, $2^A \not\subseteq A$ because a power set of any $A$ has a cardinality strictly greater than $A$ itself.

**To a question in text**

No,  $f(a)\subseteq 2^A$ does not hold in general, as $f(a)$ is by definition an *element* of $2^A$, and an element of a set is not (in general) a *subset* of the same set.

Althoug in some special cases it is, for example
$$\varnothing \in \{\varnothing, pink \} \text{ and } \varnothing \subset \{\varnothing, pink \}$$
however
$$pink \in \{\varnothing, pink \} \text{ and } pink \not\subset \{\varnothing, pink \}$$

Comment: Does $pink\not\subset\{\emptyset,pink\}$ mean that there is some $x$ such that $x\in pink$ and $x\notin\{\emptyset,pink\}$? What might that $x$ be?

Comment: *pink* is not a set here, $\neg\exists x(x\in pink)$, Replace *pink* with 7 if you like.

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks for your answer, suppose now that the cardinality of the $2^A$ is equal to the cardinality of $A$. Does $2^A \not\subseteq A$ still hold and why? (This whole post is related to Cantors theorem)

Comment: For every set $A$ you have $\left\vert 2^A\right\vert > \vert A\vert$. Supposing otherwise means making a false assumption, then you can deduct everything but that's clearly useless.

Comment: @CiaPan Its part of a proof by contradiction to assume the cardinalities are equal.

Comment: $2^A$ has all *subsets* of $A$ as its *elements*. If you want $2^A \subseteq A$, then all *elements* of $2^A$ have to be *elements* of $A$, too. That is $A$ has to contain each its *subset* as its *element*. In particular, it must contain itself as its own element: $(A\subseteq A)\implies(A\in 2^A) \implies (A\in A)$. Which contradicts the [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

Comment: @Ciapan Thanks you're very close to explaining it to me: "No,  $f(a)\subseteq 2^A$ does not hold in general, as $f(a)$ is by definition an *element* of $2^A$, and an element of a set is not (in general) a *subset* of the same set.". I just need to know _why_  an element of a set is not a subset of the same set?

Comment: You don't read carefully. Of course a set may pretty easily contain its element as a subset: $S1=\{\emptyset\}$ contains one element, which is an empty set, and clearly $\emptyset\subset S1$. But **not the other way**: a set can't contain all its subsets as elements. In particular, $S1\not\in S1$ – set $\{\emptyset\}$ has element $\emptyset = \{\}$, but has no element $S1 = \{\emptyset\}=\{\{\}\}$. BTW If you have next questions post them as questions; don't chat in comments, it's question-and-answer site.