# Can an element of a power set $2^A$ be a subset of $2^A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, intuition

This question is continued from a [previous thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293878/if-a-is-a-non-empty-set-and-2a-is-the-power-set-of-a-is-2a-subseteq-a) I started, but it had more than one question so I had to move the other question here.

For this example consider an injective map $f: A \to 2^A$ then for each element $a\in A$ $\exists$ $f(a)\subseteq A$.

But does this also mean $f(a)\subseteq 2^A$?

I ask this because when writing out a simple numerical example of such a set, say $A=\{{ 7,8\}}$ then $2^A=\{{\varnothing,\{{ 7\}},\{{ 8\}},\{{7,8\}}\}}$, however since each $f(a)$ is an element of $2^A$ then we must have $f(a)\subseteq 2^A$ since *any* set $X$ is always a subset of itself: $X\subseteq X$ right?

Thank you.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can, but it usually isn't.

We always have $\varnothing\in2^A$ and also $\varnothing\subset2^A$. So there *exists* an element of the power set $2^A$ which is also a subset of the power set $2^A$.

On the other hand, in your example, $\{7\}\in2^A$, but $\{7\}\not\subset2^A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain in simple english why $\{7\}\not\subset2^A$.?

Comment: $\{7\}$ is not a subset of $2^A$ because there exists an element of $\{7\}$ which is not an element of $2^A$. That element is, of course, $7$.

Comment: perfect, that's exactly what I needed to hear, thank you